# Assigning to position of String - "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String" (Java)

Tags: java, string

I am translating a C program to Java as part of my uni Java module work.

I have a function intended to reverse the order of a string. When assigning to a position of the string passed to the function, Eclipse IDE is telling me "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String".

```
public static void changeString(String message) {
        int len  = message.length();
        int i;
        
        for (i=0;i < len/2; i++) {
            char temp = message.charAt(i);
            message[i] = message.charAt(len-i-1); //error message here
            message[len-i-1] = temp;              //error message here
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure why there is a problem with data types in the expression - to me it should work fine. Maybe because I am indexing an array it is array type, even if `message` is a String?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Java 15.0.2, Windows 10, Eclipse 2020 -12 (4.18.0)

Comment: Since `String` is immutable, the whole premise of that method is impossible. There's no way that method will be able to reverse the parameter. You need to construct a new string that is reversed and return it. You can't translate C to Java like that just like you can't translate languages word by word.

Comment: @Kayaman I have inserted a variable msgcopy of type StringBuffer and assigned it the same value as message, because I understand StringBuffer to be mutable. Resolving this still gives the error "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to StringBuffer".

Comment: You'll need to use `StringBuffer`'s methods to mutate it. It's not an array and Java doesn't have operator overloading.

Comment: If you use `StringBuffer` you can just call its `reverse()` method

Comment: @greg-449 you just pwned my entire coursework task.... thank you

Comment: @oisinvg I'm not sure your task implied, that you can use some utility method from Java API. :) did it?..

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri I dont see why not.... I am using .length() etc, and since the task is converting C to Java to get to grips with Java I should be using the full power of the language ;)

Comment: *"you just pwned my entire coursework task"* - Only if you want to view it that way.  I expect that the *intent* of the task is to get you to write code to do the reversing ... from scratch.  Why?  As a Java programming *learning* exercise.

Comment: So as a result of the assignment, show the code performing the work with an array, followed by mentioning that in real life, you’d use `new StringBuilder(message).reverse().toString()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String is not an array (it uses one, behind the scenes, but the type itself is not), and `message[i]`, is illegal, in Java, if you want to access i<sub>*th*</sub> element of the string, referenced by `message`.

`obj[index]` is the [array access expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13) and if your aim is to write an algorithm that reverses string, it probably makes sense to first convert your string to the characters array, like:

```java
char[] msg = message.toCharArray();
```

then operate on that array;

and finally convert your array back to string, like:

```java
String convertedString = new String(msg);
```

String is an immutable type, in Java; correspondingly, working with that same reference of String doesn't make any good sense, as (1) you will be generating a new object per each operation (horrible for space complexity) on string, and (2) that means, you will *not* be effectively building a new string from the former one.

Comment: Hi, this worked. I replaced
public static void changeString(String message) {
with
public static void changeString(char[] message) {

Answer (score 0):

As String is immutable you should return new String object and use temporary array:

```
 public static String changeString(String message) {
    int len  = message.length();
    char[] arr = new char[len];
    int i;

    for (i=0;i <= len/2; i++) {
        char temp = message.charAt(i);
        arr[i] = message.charAt(len-i-1);
        arr[len-i-1] = temp;
    }

   return new String(arr);
}
```

Or you may create new StringBuilder object and use reverse method:

```
public static String changeString(String message) {
    return new StringBuilder(message).reverse().toString();
}
```